# Is there any relationship between K-Maps (Karnaugh Maps) and neural networks?

Tags: boolean-algebra, neural-networks, fuzzy-logic

Recently, I've been studying neural networks to get a better understanding of how they work. I can't help but notice a vague similarity to K-Maps or Karnaugh Maps used for determining boolean functions between inputs and outputs.

When I studied K-maps, I once had a naive and vague idea that it might be possible to decipher an algebraic formula from a pattern of numbers by applying a K-map. For instance, the input would be 1,2,3,4 and the output would be 2,4,6,8 and the K-Map would yield 2x. I figured if the K-Map operations used fuzzy logic instead of simple boolean logic, it might be possible. It seemed to silly to even consider it further.

After reading about neural networks, however, and how the inputs and outputs are processed through a network of operations, it makes me wonder if this may be influenced by K-maps. Both have  similar constraint where accuracy is dependent on the size of its input. They do differ, however, in their respective artifacts. A K-map yield an independent function, whereas a Neural Network becomes the function itself.

Is there any influence between the two historically? Is there any similarities between the two? I came across an interesting research, but being a layman, it was way over my head:

http://www.ijtrd.com/papers/IJTRD1306.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

K-maps define/describe a particular boolean function by showing the output for all possible inputs, but how that function is actually computed/implemented in terms of elementary operations like 'and', 'or', or 'not' is not specified.

Neural networks can be used to compute functions ... rather than describe their overall input-output behavior. And those functions can be just about any function, so not necessarily any boolean ones.

I suppose you could try and use a neural network to compute a boolean function as defined by a K-map ... though I see really little practical value in that when classical circuits can do the same thing ... it's overkill in a way to try and use a neural network.

I took a look at the paper you linked ... it's very poorly written, and in the end really not clear what it is proposing ... it *seems* the author is trying to use a neural network not to implement a boolean function, but rather to do the creation of groups in order to reduce/simplify a boolean circuit. What exactly that algorithm is and how that works is not clear though ... maybe this was just a 1-page summary of a much longer paper? Regardless, there is nothing about this paper that would suggest any kind of historical connection between K-maps and neural networks.

Comment: I was under the impression that K-maps. at least when I learned about it, allows you to "discover" the boolean function whose input generates the output. What you're describing seems like a truth table. Am I correct?

Comment: @user148298 Well, they are very closely related. The one difference is of course how the different possibilities are graphicall laid out. In a truth-table you have a row for each possible, and they are all under each other, while in a K-map you have those exact same possible truth-value assignments to the individual propositional variables, but by positioning them in a clever way, the K-map helps you to find simpler expressions for a boolean function.

Comment: @user148298 And yes, sometimes we use a K-map to 'discover' a boolean function in the first place. That is, with  truth--table we often *start* with an expression, and then work out its truth-conditions. In K-maps, we often go the other way around: there we often have the truth-conditions as a given, and try to end up with some expression. However, you can also use a K-map to simply an already given boolean expression, so you can start with a boolean expression, work out its truth-conditions on a K-map, and then work back to a (hopefully) simpler expression.

Comment: It's why I mentioned  my naive idea of using K-map to "discover" an underlying fuzzy algebraic function. Of course the function has a limited set of inputs and outputs, but neural networks also have a similar limitation.

Comment: Here's another paper that discusses fuzzy logic k-maps https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.5555/800111.803608